# Strange CSS/Image issue

Tags: jquery, css, hover, opacity

whilst designing the about page for my new service, i have stumbled across a bizzare problem and i am unable to work out as to the cause of it.

Hover over one of the boxes, then the icon for that box, you should notice that the image appears to darken for some strange unknown reason and i was wondering if you lovely people could help me work out what it is thats causing it.

**Website:** http://beta.idify.me/about/

Comment: don't make us go to a website, post the content / screenshot here. Think of people with future issues.

Comment: It's kinda spammy to have to visit your site to debug your issues.

Comment: Theirs no other way of showing it when i don't know what the problem actually is!

Comment: That's where your effort is asked. Try to reduce the code as much as the issue does still appear. Maybe you can tell the error by yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've got some lines in your main.js file:

```
function() {
    $("#content a img").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": 0.7 }, 200);
    },function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": 1 }, 400);
});
```

That is changing the opacity of the images, making them look darker since they are on top of a black background.

Comment: Thank you dude, i forgot about the javascript side of things, i will mark this as my accepted awswer once i can :)